# how to make file download in php only file path is saved in database

Tags: php, mysql, file, download

I am new in the field of developement so advance sorry for stupid question.
I am creating a script that upload pdf files and stored in a directory admin/uploads I am storing file path in database my complete code is as under:

```
$image="uploads/".$_FILES['image']['name'];
$pdf="uploads/".$_FILES['pdf']['name'];
mysql_query("insert into novels                 values('','$title','$author','$image','$pdf','$body','$Keywords',$cat)");
header("location:add-novel.php?cat=$cat");
?>
```

and my form is:

```
<form method="post" action="store-novel.php?cat=<?php echo $_REQUEST['cat'];?>"         enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="500" border="0"  align="left" class="innerTable">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="th">ADD NEW NOVEL</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Author</td>
<td><input type="text" name="author" id="author" />
<!--<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['cat'];?>" />-->
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image</td>
<td class="button"><input type="file" name="image" id="image" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PDF</td>
<td><input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>post body</td>
<td><textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Keywords</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Keywords" id="Keywords" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**I want to a download page from where user can download my pdf files**

Comment: Do you actually store the file on your server?

Comment: See example #1: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: have not found code to upload file on your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to download a file stored on the server?

Try this:

> $size = filesize($yourfile);
>
> header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
>
> header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
>
> header("Content-Length: $size");
>
> readfile($yourfile);

Comment: I have tried this but this code is downloading php file of my page not pdf file stored in server

Comment: Is $yourfile containing the path to the pdf?

Comment: I have privided the path and a pdf file is downloading but empty file

Comment: Ok, how is the size of the file? Is there the correct path in filesize(), too?

Comment: can you please privide me the full page code of download.php?

Comment: There is not much to add. $yourfile is the path to the file, $filename only the name of the file.

Comment: Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://digestpk.com/asif/admin/uploads/apis-php-en.pdf in /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/download.php on line 9

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/admin/config.php:7) in /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/download.php on line 11

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/admin/config.php:7) in /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/download.php on line 13

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/admin/config.php:7) in /home3/digesu6p/public_html/asif/download.php on line 15

Comment: Seems like you have output before the call. Are you sure you use download.php with the code above in it and call it directly? Or do you include download.php in config.php where in line 7 output starts (or header)

Comment: And what was the problem?

Comment: emty spaces in config.php